# invalid sign in external "numeric" value error from Npgsql Binary copy

Tags: npgsql

I get this error on using Npgsql Binary copy (see my implementation at the bottom):

```
invalid sign in external "numeric" value
```

The  RetailCost column on which it fails has the following PostgreSQL properties:

- type:     numeric(19,2)
- nullable: not null
- storage:  main
- default:  0.00

The PostgreSQL log looks like this:

```
2019-07-15 13:24:05.131 ACST [17856] ERROR:  invalid sign in external "numeric" value
2019-07-15 13:24:05.131 ACST [17856] CONTEXT:  COPY products_temp, line 1, column RetailCost
2019-07-15 13:24:05.131 ACST [17856] STATEMENT:  copy products_temp (...) from stdin (format binary)
```

I don't think it should matter, but there are only zero or positive RetailCost values (no negative or null ones)

My implementation looks like this:

```
using (var importer = conn.BeginBinaryImport($"copy {tempTableName} ({dataColumns}) from stdin (format binary)"))
{
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        importer.StartRow();
        importer.Write(product.ManufacturerNumber, NpgsqlDbType.Text);
        if (product.LastCostDateTime == null)
            importer.WriteNull();
        else
            importer.Write((DateTime)product.LastCostDateTime, NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp); 
        importer.Write(product.LastCost, NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
        importer.Write(product.AverageCost, NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
        importer.Write(product.RetailCost, NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
        if (product.TaxPercent == null)
            importer.WriteNull();
        else
            importer.Write((decimal)product.TaxPercent, NpgsqlDbType.Numeric); 
        importer.Write(product.Active, NpgsqlDbType.Boolean);
        importer.Write(product.NumberInStock, NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
    }
    importer.Complete();
}
```

Any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 2):

I caused this problem when using MapBigInt, not realizing the column was accidentally numeric(18). Changing the column to bigint fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was that the importer.Write statements was not in the same order as the dataColumns